# crontab command return codes

Tags: bash, shell, cron, return-value

When I run `crontab -r`, I get a return code equal to 1. It's actually working, it's deleting the crontab as it should. So I wonder if there is a summary of the return codes of crontab. I couldn't find it in the man page.

Comment: If the man page doesn't have exit code details, then you can safely assume that there aren't specific codes for different exit reasons. 0 is success, non-zero is failure. Most programs that don't have special exit codes just use 1 for all failures.

Comment: If you want to ask why it's reporting an error when it actually succeeded, [unix.so] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Side note: `cron` is obsolete, broken by design and better avoided.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, tell this to IBM (AIX, RHEL), Oracle (Solaris, Oracle Linux), HP (HP-UX)

Comment: @RomeoNinov They all know this. No need to tell them. They also know that `cron` has never worked properly (no log management, no service dependency tracking, no system power state(s) awareness, no “statefulness”, no security hardening options etc. etc.). Sadly, knowledge won’t make a difference unless applied. Fortunately, on an overwhelming majority of contemporary Linux distros, `cron` is completely obsolete and should be avoided.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, this is your opinion. I, working on (almost) all of the above OS, am perfectly fine with `cron`. I know how to deal and how to do the work

Comment: A **crontab** does not have "return codes". It's just a table of commands. A **process** has a return code (or better: _exit_ code) when it terminates.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Some of my statements are a matter of opinion, some ar not. That `cron` is fundamentally broken and cannot work properly, by design, that is not an opinion. (Similarly, it is not an opinion that water freezes around 0 °C.) Room for opinions exists w.r.t. whether it makes sense to fight a lost fight against the deficiencies of `cron` or to use a far superior solution (`.timer` units). Because the OP did not mention a particular system environment, I assumed a Linux-based platform with `systemd`. Other UNIX(-like) systems occur infrequently nowadays and were not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @user1934428 : `crontab` is a shell command, `crontab -r` deletes the crontab of an user. It definitely returns an exit code.

Comment: Ah, you mean the **command** `crontab`. Sorry, misunderstood you. The man-page does not specify any exit codes, but it is reasonable to assume that it follows the POSIX conventions to set code 1 for failure and 0  for success.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, `crontab` return codes are used to indicate the success or failure of a cron job. The return codes are as follows:

- **0**: [Indicates that the cron job executed successfully](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59404/how-to-control-output-from-crontab).
- **Positive number less than 256**: Indicates that the cron job failed. For example, `exit 2` would indicate a failure.

Cron will detect the exit code and, if the `MAILTO` variable is set in the crontab, it will send an email on a non-zero exit code. Additionally, if any output is sent to `stdout` or `stderr`, that is also emailed to the user, regardless of the exit code.